# Having MathJax rendering issue in "suggested edits" screen

Tags: support

I'm using the latest firefox 26.0 in PClinux and the MathJax doesn't render which makes it very difficult to read the edits.
Using Google Chrome v31 I get the same result.

[image]

But both work fine when I read posted messages or in edit mode

[image]

Any ideas?

p.s. I have no addon that prevents javascripts

---

Update: I have checked the edits I have approved that included MathJax and it seems that some do get rendered and some don't.

**These get rendered:**

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/30652

[image]

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/30554

[image]

**But these do not:**
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/30553
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/29928
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25219

So there seems to be something that triggers this behaviour.

Comment: I posted a feature request for this on Meta.SO a while back but unfortunately haven't heard anything: [LaTeX rendering for suggested edit queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200496/latex-rendering-for-suggested-edit-queue)

Comment: @PeterJ I have updated the message and added examples of edits that do render and others that don't (in the same PC)

Comment: That's interesting, in fact I'd noticed one of those edits I'd approved as well rendered it and thought it must have been changed, but when it went back to not working again thought I must have been dreaming and didn't think to check the diff again.

Comment: @PeterJ It seems that when Mathjacks is on a block at the end of the post it gets rendered, when it is between text it does not (?)

Comment: Could be a complication, I'm about to head off but had a quick look on Math.SE and they have the same problem and it looked like there might be a few things that come into play. If you don't get any responses much here in the next day you could probably change the tags to bug and mathjax - I believe SE developers get some sort of list of questions tagged bug.

Answer (score 3):

MathJax does not process any math that contains HTML tags.  The red and green change indicators are produced by inserting tags that include styling for the colors, and so if a change starts or ends within the mathematics, MathJax won't typeset it.  The examples that you give showing un-typeset math all have changes that start and end within the math.  The examples that are typeset don't.

I don't think it would be practical to have mathematics that includes changes be typeset while still being able to indicate the changes.  I think seeing the changes to the TeX code is probably the right thing in these cases.  And I'm pretty sure the SE maintainers aren't going to change this.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently got enough rep to "Review" edits.

I have seen at least one where the 'math' remained Latex-like stuff (I assume MathJax, as mentioned in the question title).

With enough complexity in the math, I found it too hard to see that the question had not been changed in some key way. I tried "rendered output" and "markdown", but they didn't seem to help. They were both 'broken'.

I can appreciate the difficulty of combining HTML and other markdown in the 'diff' view.

However, my problem seems soluble.

I would like a way to see the *normally rendered view*. No colour highlighting. No markdown. Only the view that should be rendered for a normal user.

Is their a way to see that view? Or, is there a reason this can't be raised as a change request? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Almost two years later and this is still a problem.  The lack of rendering even makes it difficult to see if the equation has been corrupted. I feel that more "diligent" users will simply skip the edit, whereas others might **approve a bad edit** assuming that it is good.

The following is the first edit of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/204917/38335) answer.

[image]

Did the editor transpose two variables? I can't tell, either.

I have found that I can click the "Improve Edit" button and see the rendered MathJax, but I no longer have a side-by-side comparison.

Anyway, I like @gbulmer 's solution. Strip the color formatting markdown out of MathJaX equations, and all manner of things will be well :)